# Track mobile devices in offline mode?

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone-8

I'm interested in developing an application which can keep track of a device's location and view the coordinates in a map.

But, in offline mode ( the tracked device can or can not have a internet connection ).

Here's an example:
[Device A] -> NO internet connection.

[Device B] -> Has internet connection.
Basically,it can view the location of Device A on a map in the application.

Is this possible?
Android/WP

Comment: You mean real-time? Up to date? And device A has no internet connection, ever? Then no, that's not possible.

Comment: is bluetooth an option?

Comment: What would device A be connected to that allows the second device to track it's location? Your question doesn't have enough information to explain how you intend to enable that support.

Answer (score 0):

For WP8 this is not possible.  The best you could hope for was a WP app with a periodic background agent that will run at most once every 30 minutes and can grab the GPS position and post it if a web connection is available.  If a connection is not possible you would have to cache the values until a connection becomes available and push the list to the connection.

<strike>Continuous GPS would require the app to be the foreground app, so if the user uses other apps it would cause a break in the GPS tracking.</strike>

EDIT:  See WiredPrairie's comment below for continuous GPS tracking.  The issue over lack of connectivity to upload position data still stands, through and would require caching if you intended to show the full route if the device, rather than just it's current position.

Comment: It is possible to track the user's location: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: How could you even begin to answer the OPs question? He has provided little or no information. What does he mean by "offline mode" does he mean no wifi? No Cellular? No Bluetooth? Windows Phone has multiple ways of getting a Geo Location.

Comment: Thanks, WiredPrairie, that's new to me and will prove useful in a future project I have in mind.  I guess I need to re-read all the geo-location APIs etc.

Comment: AMR -- I assumed he meant internet connection for uploading position data, which seems to be the case now that he has added more information.